# How can I change my steam address?

Tags: steam

I recently moved to a different location. How can I change the address listed in my steam account?

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually save your address anywhere in Steam.

You can change your location in by modifying your Steam profile, and you can fill out a new billing address when you buy a new game. Before you buy anything, your address isn't used for anything.

Comment: Indeed.  The address in the profile and stored billing information is disregarded to the point that Steam won't use local servers for downloading files unless you specify it in the client preferences.  It's never been autodetected for me, either.

Comment: I've had it auto-detected for me before; usually when I switch to Taiwan (or somewhere equally remote) to download new TF2 patches when the NA servers are all "too busy to process your request".

Comment: Not true. Steam is prefilling my billing address with an old one, even though I deleted the payment method a long time ago/never actually added it.

Answer (score 3):

The only addresses stored in Steam are billing addresses linked to payment methods. So if you don't have a payment method saved, you won't have any kind of an address.

A billing address can be changed by deleting a previously saved payment method and replacing it with a new one. Payment methods are managed in the Store & Purchase History section of the [account details page](https://store.steampowered.com/account/) (available by browser, or via the Steam client at Steam → Settings → Account → View Account Details).